Creating CRUD using Apollo Graphql and Next.js
I am using React (Ts) , Next.js 14 and Graphql over Apollo server. I have a local JSON file, which I am able to render, however I am stuck with add, delete and update.Any help for a newbie like me will be great. At least if I can add data .Also using React MUI.I am using both Apollo server and client.
UserForm.tsx
async  function UserForm(){   

  return (
    <form  className='contact-form' >      
      <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
        <InputLabel  htmlFor="firstName">First Name</InputLabel >
        <TextField
          className='name'
          name='name'
          type='text'
         
        /> 
      </FormControl >
       <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="phone">Phone</InputLabel>
        <TextField
          className='email'
          name='email'         
          type='text'
                  /> 
      </FormControl>
      <FormGroup >
             <Button variant="contained" >Add         
        </Button>
      </FormGroup>
    </form>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
TypeDef.tsx
export const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    email: String!     
  }

  type Query {
    getUsers: [User!]! 
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(name: String!, email: String!): User! 
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;   

Resolver
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
     getUsers: () => {
        return data 
     }
    },   }
Data.json
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alice", "email": "alice@example.com" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob", "email": "bob@example.com" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Bobbb", "email": "bobbb@example.com" }
  ]


For mutations your resolvers need to write your data somewhere, most likely in a database. Since you are using a json data file you could also read/write that file using node. None of this has anything to do with react btw.

So the resolver doesn't write directly to the JSON api over apollo server?

What JSON api are you talking about?

Its a JSON file , I have in the project directory and I am using Apollo Server to access it.

Apollo server doesn't have anything to write JSON files. Look at node's fs.writeFile

okay, thanks. totally new and must have sounded silly. i will have a look
